# Linear statistical model with two-class variables

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, nonlinear-regression, multi-class

Suppose I have a set of (discrete) variables, say $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Each $i$ belongs to either class A or class B. When it belongs to A the contribution is $Y_{A,i}f(X_i)$, and when it belongs to B the contribution is $Y_{B,i}g(X_i)$, so that the final outcome is $Z=\sum_{i=1}^N Y_{A,i}f(X_i) I_{\{i \in A\}} + Y_{B,i}g(X_i) I_{\{i \in B\}}$, where $I_{\{.\}}$ denotes the indicator-function.

The values for $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are given, as are the functions $f$ and $g$. Now suppose I have $M$ obervations for $Z$, what method do you advice to

(i)  Identify whether $i$ is in $A$ or $B$

(ii) Estimate the values for $Y_{A,i}$ (if $i\in A)$ and $Y_{B,i}$ (if $i \in B$).

I tried to estimate the coefficients $Y_{A,i}$ and $Y_{B,i}$ using standard linear regression, assuming that $i\in A$ for all $i$ or $i \in B$ for all $i$, but that gives bad results.

(iii) What if I have $M$ different inputs $X_{j,1},\dots,X_{j,N}$, for $j=1,\dots,M$ and one observation for $Z$ for each input?

Edit:

As an example, take the following R-code:

```
N=50
M=10
X=rbinom(N*M,1,0.5)-rbinom(N*M,1,0.5) #Generate -1, 0, 1 variables
dim(X) <- c(N,M)
pA=1/2 #pB=1-pA
XA = X #f(x)=x
XB = -X^2 + 1 #g(x)=-x^2+1
isA = as.logical(rbinom(M,1,pA))
YA = rnorm(M,1,5) #generate coefficients
YB = rnorm(M,1,5) #generate coefficients
Z = XA[,isA] %*% YA[isA] + XB[,!isA] %*% YB[!isA] #Calculate Z without noise
Z = Z+rnorm(N,sd=sqrt(var(Z))) #add noise
```

Thus given the observations `Z` and the input data `XA, XB` (these are known) I want to estimate `isA, YA[isA]` and `YB[!isA]`.

Comment: What is $Y$? Maybe a data example would help to understand the notational problems.

Comment: Demands (i) and (ii) are strongly cnonected. Are the functions `f` and `g` very different from each other (e.g. linear versus exponential)? So you have a set of M input sets $\{X_i\}$ and some observations for `Z` but do not know which input set $\{X_i\}$ produced which `Z`?

Comment: The functions $f$ and $g$ can in general be anything and are not equal. As an example you might take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, if that helps. 

I do know which observation $Z$ belongs to which input set $\{X_i\}$.

Comment: Solutions to your type of problem seem to be classified as `latent class regression models`. Maybe this paper can serve as a starting point: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.mcm.2005.01.031

Comment: Thank you for the paper. Their problem seems to be slightly different though. In their case each observation for $Z$ seems to belong to a certain class, i.e. $Z_j=\sum_{i=1}^N Y_{A,i}f(X_{j,i})$ or $Z_j=\sum_{i=1}^N Y_{B,i}g(X_{j,i})$ in my notation. In my case each of the variables $\{X_i\}$ belong to a certain class, but they belong to the same class for every input, i.e. $X_{1,1} \in A \implies X_{2,1},\dots,X_{M,1} \in A$

Comment: @MichaelMayer I added a (simulated) data example to the post.

Comment: Can I assume that the $X_i$ are all positive and discrete as in your example? Furthermore, can I assume that the class membership follows a binomial distribution, i.e. class membership of one $X_i$ is independent of class membership of $X_j$?

Comment: In my example I chose $X_i \in \{-1,0,1\}$, but positive (and discrete) $X_i$ is fine with me (if that simplifies the problem). Also, class membership of the $X_i$'s can be assumed to be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated the problem, the variables $X_i$ are ordered, so if an $X_i$ is associated with class $A$ for one input set, $X_i$ is also associated to the same class in all the other input sets. This helps enormously to restrict the number of possible models. So your model is of the form:
$$Z=\sum_{i=1}^N Y_i\,f(X_i) I_{\{i \in A\}} + Y_{i}\,g(X_i) I_{\{i \in B\}}$$

Thus, you have a model with $2N$ parameters; $N$ multiplication factors $Y_i$ and $N$ binary variables for the class membership. You can use maximum-likelihood-estimation (MLE) to get the classification and the coefficients. Since you assume that the true $Z$ value is diluted by Gaussian noise, your log-likelihood is (after shifting by an irrelevant constant regarding maximization) proportional to:

$$\text{LL} \propto -\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=j}^{M}(Z_j-\tilde{Z}_j)^2$$

where $\tilde{Z}_j$ is the model prediction for the given set of observations $X_{j,i}$ and $Z_j$the observed effect for input set $j$ using a specific set of model parameters. Now, the idea is simple: choose the model parameters in such a way that the $\text{LL}$-value is maximized. In the case of 10 predictor variables this can be done by exhaustive search: for every possible class assignment of the $X_i$, solve the linear regression problem. In this way you get for $N=10$ a number of 1024 different models. Pick the model with the highest log-likelihood value. I wrote a small R function that works together with your example to calculate the log-likelihoods:

```
judgeModels <- function()
{
  resfrm <- data.frame(replicate(M,logical(2^M)),LL=Inf)

  for (i in seq(0,2^M-1))
  { 
    # generate next classification possibility
    isA <- rep(FALSE,M)
    tmp <- i
    for (j in seq(M))
    {
      isA[j] <- tmp %% 2 == 1
      tmp <- trunc(tmp / 2)
    }
    # set design matrix according to classification 
    curXA <- XA; curXA[,!isA] <- 0
    curXB <- XB; curXB[,isA] <- 0
    XAB <- curXA + curXB
    # solve the linear regression problem
    b <- solve(t(XAB)%*%XAB)%*%t(XAB)%*%Z
    # calculate the negative log-likelihood
    resid <- XAB%*%b - Z
    estvar <- 1/length(Z)*sum(resid^2)
    # store the result
    resfrm[i+1,1:M] <- isA
    resfrm[i+1,M+1] <- estvar
  } 
  # order models according to their performance
  # best first, worst last
  resfrm <- resfrm[order(resfrm[,M+1]),]
  rownames(resfrm) <- seq(nrow(resfrm))
  return(resfrm)
}
```

It returns all possible models together with their log-likelihood score. The lower the score, the better rated the model. Here an example of how to use the function:

```
resfrm <- judgeModels()
# display top rated models
resfrm[1:5,]
# rank of the true model 
trueidx <- which(apply(resfrm[,1:M],1,function(x) all(x==isA)))
resfrm[trueidx,]
```

If you play a bit with this function, you will realise that 50 input sets are to less to find the right classification with high certainty. You need a sample size > 1000 to achieve this goal. However, the smaller the variance of the Gaussian noise added to $Z$, the smaller the required sample size to get the right classification, e.g. try `Z = Z+rnorm(N,sd=1)` and look what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! I already thought 50 inputs would not be enough here, they were just example numbers. Also how would you work with $M>10$? For $M=30$ checking all models does not seem feasible anymore, and $M=100$ is totally impossible.

Comment: For a large number of predictor variables one can rely on heuristics. A simple one could be: start from a random class assignment. Randomly switch the class membership of one variable and look if the score improved. If yes, keep the change, if no, keep the old configuration. Do this until convergence is reached. This procedure could be refined by randomly switching the class of two (and more variables) at once.

Comment: That seems like a good suggestion indeed, thanks. Would it be possible to cleverly pick the initial position and/or class membership to switch, instead of picking them at random?

Comment: Without any prior knowledge I don't think so. However, you don't need to sample from the beginning. Let's assume $M=50$. Firstly, switch systematically each variable, which requires 50 steps. Afterwards switch systematically each combination of two variables at once, which requires 50*49/2=1225 steps; 3 vars at once: 19600 steps; 4 vars at once 230300 steps. Hence it seems feasible to perform an exhaustive search up to three var switches at once. From that point on, you can randomly sample 4 vars switches and so on, if necessary.

Comment: Another note: this optimization problem seems perfectly suited to be solved by a genetic algorithm: the DNA is given by a logical vector specifying class membership of the vars, the initial population consists of individuals with randomly assigned DNA sequences; also mutation and selection operators can be defined in a straightforward way. The result is a population of really well performing individuals.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with genetic algorithms. Could you give me a pointer? The wikipedia article is not very helpful. Or, at least, I don't see how this could solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe you are better off with a [tutorial](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat1.html). In your case the bit string specifies the class assignment of the variables and the fitness function is given by the likelihood.